# How to produce CSS, ">", using Garden

Tags: css, clojurescript, garden

I would like to produce, say, below CSS using [Garden](https://github.com/noprompt/garden/).

```
.block-main > header {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 32px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

So far, I've no idea, how to do `>` ; neither I can find any example anywhere. Please help.

Comment: Scan the github page for 'Combinators descendant' and you have your answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `garden.selectors/>`.  E.g.

```
(css [(garden.selectors/> :.block-main :header) {:height "100px"}])
; ⇒ ".block-main > header {\n  height: 100px;\n}"
```